# Delete directory of files, UI is not updating

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I am trying to delete a directory of files, and for each file I delete, I want to update the UI with the filename that is currently being deleted.

Here is the code I have in my ViewModel:

```
private void ExecuteDeleteCommand()
{
    var files = new DirectoryInfo(BackupDirectory).GetFiles();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        ActivityFileName = file.Name;
        file.Delete();
    }
}
```

XAML (nothing special, just a `TextBlock`):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ActivityFileName}"/>
```

What's happening is, the files in that directory are deleted, but the UI is only updating on the **VERY LAST** file in the iteration.

`ActivityFileName` calls `OnPropertyChanged`, so I know that isn't the problem.

I have created a directory that has approximately 23k files, so I know I should be seeing something other than the last file when it completes.

I'm just puzzled as to why it's not updating the UI on each call.

Comment: Is the UI frozen entirely during this operation?  It sounds like the operation is blocking the UI thread and should be done asynchronously.

Comment: @David Duh! That was exactly what the problem was. If you post as answer, i'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: Other answers look like they have it covered :)  It's odd that I can't find an asynchronous delete operation, I wonder if there's something in the kernel which prevents that from being possible.  *Ideally* this whole method could just be `async` and would simply `await` the delete operations, but I guess a background worker is the next best thing in this case.  (I suppose you *could* make the method `async` (use `Task` instead of `void`!) and do something like `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => file.Delete());`  It won't be kernel-level async, but it should free up the UI thread.)

Comment: @David I ended up passing the method to a background worker and it ran as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the UI thread to do your work.  As a result, the UI won't be updated until ExecuteDeleteCommand() returns.

If you want the UI to update then you need to do the work on a background thread.  Keep in mind that the OnPropertyChanged() calls will need to be dispatched back to the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx), but in the file deletion thread, use the `ReportProgress` method to pass the file name back to the UI thread.  Then, in the UI thread, subscribe to the [Background Worker's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) `ProgressChanged` event and retrieve the file name that you passed in during the call to `ReportProgress`.  You can use the UserState object to pass the file name to the UI thread in order to tell the user what file you're currently working on.

Answer (score 1):

The UI thread is just not fast enough to keep up with the flood of events that are coming from the delete loop. At the same time, I'm assuming that the user is not trying to scan the 23k file names to ensure that everything is working correctly.

If a complete audit list of the affected file is required, the values could be appended to the multiline text box so that the changes would be apparent at the end of processing.

That being said, you can force a redraw. Since you already have your typical OnPropertyChanged implemented, just include another event for the dispatcher to redraw:

```
    private static readonly Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
    }
```

See [Refresh / Update WPF controls](http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/08/25/refresh--update-wpf-controls.aspx) for details.